# Does readonly property for IBOutlet Work and would it be Preferable?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, iboutlet

In code that I'm inheriting, I've seen the following:

```
@property (readonly) IBOutlet UIImageView * bgImage;
```

When I would expect a retain memory model like:

```
@property (readonly, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView * bgImage;
```

I'm confused why the first property definition works without causing problems.

Also, there is a `release` in dealloc as you might expect like:

```
-(void)dealloc
{
   [_bgImage release];
   [super dealloc];
}
```

I'd appreciate if anyone can come up with an explanation for this.  I've spoken with the original developer and he was trying to write more concise code which is why he left out the `retain` in the memory model (seemed unnecessary).

I wonder if the IBOutlet is basically treated like an ivar IBOutlet statement because it is readonly (no setter to use, thus the default assign memory model makes no difference).

If the IBOutlet is never expected to change, would using a readonly property with no memory model actually be a preferable way to define properties?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The nib loader on iOS creates the objects in the nib and then autoreleases them. When it establishes connections to outlets, it uses `setValue:forKey:`, which will call the setter method for that key. If no setter is defined, such as when the `IBOutlet` is a `readonly` property, the object is retained *anyways* before being assigned. 
(This is a paraphrase of [Managing Nib Objects in iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW35) in the Resource Programming Guide.)

So in actual fact, whether the outlet is declared as `retain` or `assign`, the object at the other end *is* owned by the object with the outlet. Either it is retained by the setter method, or it is retained by `setValue:forKey:` when a setter is not found. Since there is no other possible owner in the second case, you may consider the object with the outlet to be the owner. Therefore the object in the nib should be released in `dealloc`.

I agree with you that this memory condition should be made explicit by changing the property attributes to include `retain`.* Whether or not it's `readonly` doesn't seem to make a difference (however, see below). Conceptually, yes, the object is read-only, so whether to mark it explicitly as such depends on whether you consider that suitably documented by the fact that it's an `IBOutlet`.

UPDATE:
Paul.s's comment below prompted me to do a quick test. I created a `UIView` subclass that logs its `alloc`, `retain`, `release`, and `autorelease` calls, stuck an instance of it into a nib, and gave the app delegate a `IBOutlet` via a property.

Tallying up the reference counting activity by hand, the instance came out with a net 0 count when the property was `(readwrite, assign)`. It was net +1 when the property was declared the recommended way, `(readwrite, retain)`, and *also* when it was `(readonly, assign)`. All of this is pretty much as expected -- when it is `(readwrite, assign)`, the assigning setter is used to make the connection, and no retain is made. When it is `readonly`, the connection mechanism falls back on doing its own retain.

Most interestingly, when I tried to crash the app by changing the background color of this view with the property declared `(readwrite, assign)` (i.e., when it had presumably been deallocated), I saw one last call to `retain` pop up.

I think what this comes down to is: follow Apple's recommendation -- they know what's going on behind the scenes, and (barring bugs) aren't going to steer you wrong.

(Another thing to take away is that, as always, worrying about absolute reference counts is not going to be terribly useful -- the count went all the way up to 6 at one point, over the course of two dozen calls to `retain` and `release` --  you just need to worry about retains and releases that you cause directly.)

---

*Of course, this changes under ARC. The info I paraphrased is in the "Legacy Patterns" section of its chapter. Under ARC, the recommendation is for `IBOutlets` to be `weak` unless they are top-level, in which case they should be `strong`. Doing it that way means you are relying on the view hierarchy (views retaining their subviews) to maintain itself.

Comment: `whether the outlet is declared as retain or assign, the object at the other end is owned by the object with the outlet` (this is not so clear) is this only if it's set to `readonly`? If it was `(assign, readwrite)` then surely the non-retaining setter would be used and no `retain` would be taken? - I only mention as it's the only part of your answer that was a bit ambiguous

Comment: I think so...that's certainly what it seems to say.

Comment: @Paul.s: see my update -- I decided to count the reference activity by hand and the results were, I think, instructive.

Comment: Nice bit of curious investigation

Comment: +1 marked as answer.  However, which way would you recommend?  If you don't plan on ever changing the IBOutlet instance, would the readonly way be preferred?  Personally I like the `(readwrite, retain)`.  Usually I write them like `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *myView` (readwrite is default, so doesn't need to be written explicitly).

Comment: @Sam: I think you should go with Apple's recommendation: `(readwrite, nonatomic, retain)` (as you say, you can leave out the explicit `readwrite`). Meaning no disrespect to your coworker, concision certainly contributes to readability, but sometimes writing what everyone expects is more important. If he had done it the recommended way, you wouldn't have had to spend any time at all puzzling over the implications. While it was an interesting thing to look into, you probably could have gotten (more important) things done in that time.

Answer (score 2):

I have reported a bug with Apple that if you create IBOutlet instance variables instead of properties, that Xcode will still automatically create release's in dealloc etc. Xcode for iOS apps seems to always create releases for IBOutlet whether its correct or not.

Personnel I don't like property IBOutlet as it means you declare them as readwrite, which means they are documented as readwrite, but most of the time, (nearly always), IBOutlet should conceptually be readonly. Obviously they have to be readwrite to set initially.

Comment: You can declare `@property (nonatomic, readonly)` in the public interface and `@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet` in the class extension.